# Window's XP is intermittently not responding to wired network

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wired-networking

I have a Windows XP machine on our network that is intermittently losing the network.

The user asked me to find out why she was unable to connect to a piece of software she uses that runs on one of our network servers.  When I checker her PC I noticed it was not able to connect to anything on the network.

When I try to ping our main server, I receive a "Request timed out." error.  Everyone once in a while as I sit here I will notice that it does receive a reply from the server, never more than 10 or 20, then returns to timing out.

The machine has a static IP I set.  I ensured the settings were correct with a different computer plugged into the same cable.  I have narrowed it down to the XP computer.

So far I have tried changing her IP settings, disabling the Window's Firewall, and even installing a PCI ethernet card (the main wired network card is build into the mother board).  No matter what I do I have the same problem where it works for a few seconds from time to time then fails again.

This is the only machine in our network that is having this problem.  We do have DHCP on our network, but it is not enabled to use address from the same range as the static IP I assigned.

I did have this same problem on the same machine a few days ago, but the problem vanished while I was working on it and appeared to be good to go.  I honestly had bigger things to work on and went on my way.

I have tried searching superuser for answer but did not see anything that fixed my problem.  What are some next steps I should take?

Comment: Have you checked the switch port?  Have your tried switching cables?  What about the integrity of the wall plug-->switch infrastructure?

Comment: have you tried resetting the tcp/ip stack in XP?

Comment: I did swap cables and had no issues with my laptop connected to the same cable. I left for a hour or so and when I just came back it seems to be working fine again.

Comment: I just used the command "netsh int ip reset C:/resetip.log" and the problem appears to have gone away.  (it returned since my last comment once I switched some cables around to get the PC back under the desk).  I will wait and see what tomorrow holds at this point, the lady who uses the machine left for the day.  Thanks so far!

Comment: I have an XP system in my network, with a fixed intranet address, assigned in order to act as a local server, and I have never had anything like this problem, so I agree that it sounds like a hardware problem. It is obviously not in the XP network adapter since you have substituted this, so I concur that cabling is the most likely suspect, but try swapping the router port first: quick and easy to do, in order to eliminate an unlikely router port fault.

Comment: (My comment crossed with the last two, so it does not take account of them, but I would still suspect a dodgy cable: unplugging and plugging in again can often fix a wiring fault temporarily.)

Comment: just trying a laptop with that cable might not be enough of a test. Try another cable with the computer.  I've seen a VGA port  that was strict / funny about the VGA cable connected to it, dunno if an ethernet card might be like that.  See if different cables produce different results with your computer.

Comment: After more investigation and trial and error, I have found out some more symptoms.  She is now running with a new IP address.  Something else appears to have taken her old IP, and that is a separate issue I need to address.  I also swapped the cable running to her machine with the PC on the desk directly in front of her, no change.  Also tried a new LAN adapter card, no change.  It will work for some time, but she says after a while of using an application that runs on one of our servers she loses connection and restarts her PC. I found I can also regain connection by restarting LAN adapter.

Comment: I eventually was able to get her device working again. I used this resource:  [The Nuclear Option: Resetting The Crap Out Of Your Network Adapters in Vista](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx)     This worked fine in XP.